# Dedicated method of enumerating above minipages

Tags: tikz-pgf, enumerate, minipage

I want to enumerate a set of tikzpictures with the label being above and in the center of each picture. I would like to do it with an enumerate environment and not to have to insert each label manually.

The first set of pictures is what I do manually and the second set is a not-so-good enumeration.
[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelformat=empty}
\usepackage[cm]{fullpage}
\begin{document}    
        \begin{figure}[H]
            \begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\textwidth  }
                \caption{(1)}
                \centering
                \begin{tikzpicture}             
                \tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}        
                \tkzDrawCircle[R](A,1.2 cm)                         
                \end{tikzpicture}
            \end{minipage}
            \qquad
            \begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\textwidth  }
                \caption{(2)}
                \centering
                \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.92]
                    \tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}        
                    \tkzDrawCircle[R](A,1.2 cm)             
                \end{tikzpicture}
            \end{minipage}
            \qquad
            \begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\textwidth  }
                \caption{(3)}   
                \centering
                \begin{tikzpicture}
                    \tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}        
                    \tkzDrawCircle[R](A,1.2 cm)         
                \end{tikzpicture}
            \end{minipage}          
        \end{figure}         
        
        
        
        \begin{multicols}{3}
            \begin{enumerate}
                \item 
                \begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth  }
                    \begin{tikzpicture}
                        \tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}        
                        \tkzDrawCircle[R](A,1.2 cm)         
                    \end{tikzpicture}
                \end{minipage}
                \item 
                \begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth  }
                    \begin{tikzpicture}
                        \tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}        
                        \tkzDrawCircle[R](A,1.2 cm)         
                    \end{tikzpicture}
                \end{minipage}
                \item 
                \begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth  }
                    \begin{tikzpicture}
                        \tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}        
                        \tkzDrawCircle[R](A,1.2 cm)         
                    \end{tikzpicture}
                \end{minipage}
            \end{enumerate}             
        \end{multicols}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Are the numbers supposed to be subfigure numbers or something different?

Comment: I want them to be subfigures enumerations but I want to use the enumerate environment.

Comment: Would you be fine with automatically generated numbers using an approach other than using an enumerate environment? This is quite easy to achieve using the subcaption package.

Comment: I suppose I would like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help of the `subcaption` package:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelformat=empty}
\usepackage[cm]{fullpage}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{\arabic{subfigure}}
\begin{document}    
        \begin{figure}
            \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
                \caption{}
                \centering
                \begin{tikzpicture}             
                \tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}        
                \tkzDrawCircle[R](A,1.2 cm)                         
                \end{tikzpicture}
            \end{subfigure}
            \qquad
            \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
                \caption{}
                \centering
                \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.92]
                    \tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}        
                    \tkzDrawCircle[R](A,1.2 cm)             
                \end{tikzpicture}
            \end{subfigure}
            \qquad
            \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
                \caption{}   
                \centering
                \begin{tikzpicture}
                    \tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}        
                    \tkzDrawCircle[R](A,1.2 cm)         
                \end{tikzpicture}
            \end{subfigure}          
        \end{figure}     
\end{document}
```

[image]